# AlertDialog.Builder does not stay on screen

Tags: android, android-activity

In my application I am showing AlertDialog.Builder

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

and in this alert there is one EditText and PositiveButton.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setMessage("Enter Text");

final EditText input = new EditText(this);
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);

alert.setView(input);
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
if(input.getTest().getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Please enter some text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
alert.show();
```

If nothing is entered then it shows **Please enter some text** on toast and the dialog is closed but I want that Alert dialog to be closes. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the dialog first and then show.

```
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
            alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setMessage("Enter Text");

final EditText input = new EditText(this);
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);

alert.setView(input);
alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {}
}

final AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
dialog.show();

dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
      if(input.getTest().getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
      Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Please enter some text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
});
```